# Pass data from one Razor page to another without using route parameters

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a page `add` which will add an item to the database on `OnValidSubmit` and then redirect to a page `list`. On the page `list` I want to show a success message like "*item added*".

I want to show the success message *"item added"* only once. If the user refreshes the page, it shall be gone. So a route parameter which is passed via the `URL` seems to be the wrong thing, as this will survive refreshes.

So, how can I one-time pass a "show success message" flag and maybe some additional data like the item name?

Hint: I am using Blazor server-side

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are so many ways to do this... Have you tried using Session?

Comment: I am new to Blazor and only knew about route parameters. With session, how can I distinguish a direct user call to `list` from a redirect to `list` from `add`? As everything on Blazor server-side runs on the server, is there really nothing like `navigate(page, dataToBePassedWithoutModifyingTheUrl)`?

Comment: Before redirect from add, set the session value. In the list, if the value is not found, don't display it. At the end of the page, delete or change the session value.

Comment: while it's unlikely, this still wouldn't make it impossible that a parallel call to `list` takes the session value instead of the `list` that was called from `add`. Still wondering if there is no better of directly passing data - as everything is server-side, it should be possible. wondeirng if nothing like that was built in.

Comment: I think I know how to tackle this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you navigate from one page to another, all of the state within the page is lost.

What isn't lost is the scoped dependency container. So, if you create an object that you register with `services.AddScoped<MyStateObject>()` then you'll be able to access that object instance throughout your app - not only across pages but also within multiple components simply by injecting it

```
@inject MyStateObject State

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(State.Message))
{
  <div class="alert alert-success">@State.Message</div>
}

@code
{
  protected override OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
  {
    State.Message = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this has the same issue as using a session - how do you guarantee that the success message is shown on the `list` page that `add` redirect to and not on a `list` page that maybe was opened by the user on a second browser tab?

Comment: No, it hasn't any issue. That is the correct answer, and he's suggesting you to define a service class to do the job. This is the the best way to share state within components. Please accept the answer.

Comment: Other than what peter and enet have advised you, you can look at some way to persist the state via a database for example.

Comment: State isn't shared across tabs

Comment: Re: "how do you guarantee .." - this is implicit when your code does the redirecting. A user can't intervene in there.

Comment: ah great, wasn't aware of scoped services and that they work like this. great, thank you all!